# git merge discards new changes without conflict

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, conflict, atlassian-sourcetree

I have really strange problem that happens sometimes in my team.
Let me describe it using the picture:

[image: Commits]

Let us say that we have two branches that have same base commit "commit 1".
Now, in "commit 2", someone added new line to file X.txt.
In the "commit 3", somebody added the line file Y.txt.

After that there are some more commits, some more branches and finaly we are merging those two branches. Seams like totaly normal merge.

But sometimes something strange happen because Git can decide that the change that was made in the green branch in the Y file should be discarded, even if there were totaly no changes of this file in red branch.
Sometimes it even delete files that was added to the green branch but not to red branch.

I'm totally puzzled, I have no idea why this is happening.
We are using SourceTree, and project is in Unity.

I will be gratefull for any ideas ;-).

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This shouldn't happen under normal usage. Unless you're cherrypicking commits from the other branch, or creating a file with the same name on both branches.

Comment: Well the problem is that it's difficult to give such example becasue it happens at random (at least in my observation). And we have quite epanded tree and i don't know how to replicat this. We didn't use cherypiciking lately so it cant't be the cause.

Comment: Does `git log --full-history` show you different output than a normal `git log`?  If so, somebody's done a merge and discarded those changes, probably by doing a `git merge -sours`.

Comment: The output of git log and git log --full-history are exactly the same. Also, my team uses the Graphical UI of sourcetree, nobody would use git merge -sours manually. Ist there a possibility that sourcetree sometimes change to that merge strategy? I couldn't find any way to change merge strategy of sourcetree, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

> But sometimes something strange happen because git can decide that the change that was made in the green branch in the Y file should be discarded, even if there were totally no changes of this file in red branch.
>
> Sometimes it even delete files that was added to the green branch but not to red branch.

It depend of the merge direction: which is the source branch, and which is the destination branch in the merge?

- if red is merged into green (`git checkout green`, `git merge red`), files modified in green but not in red would remain unchanged.
  And files added in green but considered deleted in red could be deleted.
- if green is merged in to red (`git checkout red`, `git merge green`), those same issues should not happen.